# AlternativeText dos sharpes para guardar config

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

ola
gostaria de saber se existe algum problema/risco de se usar a propriedade  AlternativeText  dos objetos sharpes para guardar parâmetros de funcionamento
tem algum risco de do nada esses dados serem apagados/substituídos de repente por outras ações dentro do próprio office?
estou montando um esquema para usar shape "formas" como botões especiais como grupos de option button e checkbox e pensei desse espaço para ter a configuração de funcionamento

como não era prioridade eu deixei um pouco de lado, mas parte do que eu fiz , tem algo mais avançado mas nem achei a planilha

```
Sub SelecDigitoFORMA()
     Dim Nn As Long, Cj As Long, dsL As Long, dsC As Long, V As Long
     Dim Sh As Shape     'Object
     Dim ConfigB() As String     ' matriz de configuração
     Dim CfB(1 To 20) As Long     ' define possição das configurações
     CfB(1) = 0          'Tipo= 0 controle, 1 chekcbox ,2 option, 3 rotativo
     CfB(2) = 1          'Estado= 0 desativado, 1 ativado, possição no rotativo
     CfB(3) = 2          'valor se desaAtivado
     CfB(4) = 3          'valor se ativado
     CfB(5) = 4
     CfB(6) = 5     'Linha inicial ( 0 PARA POSSIÇÃO  TopLeftCell)
     CfB(7) = 6     'deslocamento LINHA
     CfB(8) = 7     'coluna inicial ( 0 PARA POSSIÇÃO  TopLeftCell)
     CfB(9) = 8     'deslocamento COLUNA
     CfB(10) = 9     '
     CfB(11) = 10     '
     CfB(12) = 11    '
     CfB(13) = 12    '
     CfB(14) = 13     '
     CfB(15) = 14    'cor fundo se desativado
     CfB(16) = 15     'cor fundo se ativado
     CfB(17) = 16     'cor texto se desativado
     CfB(18) = 17    'cor texto se ativado
     CfB(19) = 18    'possição de sequencia acionamento
     CfB(20) = 19    'Nome botão
     'ActiveSheet.Shapes.SelectAll

     Set Sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
     'Sh.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(0, 128, 64)
     ccs = Sh.TopLeftCell.Column
     cs = Cells(1, ccs).Value2
     NWP = Sh.OnAction & cs
     Gn = Sh.Title       ' nome grupo
     pre = Sh.OLEFormat.Object.Caption & ccs

     ConfigB = Split(Sh.AlternativeText, ",")
     If UBound(ConfigB) < 1 Then Exit Sub

     If ConfigB(CfB(1)) = "0" Then
          V = ConfigB(CfB(2))     'Cells(2, cs + 1).Value2
          If V = 1 Then

               ' Cells(ConfigB(CfB(6)) + ConfigB(CfB(7)), ConfigB(CfB(8)) + ConfigB(CfB(9))).Value2 = 0    ' Val(ConfigB(CfB(3)))

               ConfigB(CfB(2)) = 0
               Sh.BackgroundStyle = 3
               Sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground2
          Else
               ConfigB(CfB(2)) = 1
               Sh.BackgroundStyle = 1:
               Sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText2
          End If
          Sh.AlternativeText = Join(ConfigB, ",")

          For Each Sh2 In ActiveSheet.Shapes
               ccs = Sh2.TopLeftCell.Column
               gcs = Cells(1, ccs).Value2
               BBN = Sh2.OnAction & gcs
               If BBN = NWP Then
                    If Gn = Sh2.Title Then
                         ConfigB2 = Split(Sh2.AlternativeText, ",")
                         If UBound(ConfigB2) < 19 Then Exit Sub
                         If ConfigB2(CfB(1)) <> "0" Then
                              ConfigB2(CfB(1)) = Val(ConfigB(CfB(2))) + 1
                         End If
                         Sh2.AlternativeText = Join(ConfigB2, ",")
                    End If
               End If
          Next Sh2

     Else
'==========================================================
          With ActiveSheet
               For Each Sh In .Shapes
                    adf = Sh.TopLeftCell.Address     'Local
                    ccs = Range(adf).Column
                    lls = Range(adf).Row
                    gcs = Cells(1, ccs).Value2
                    BBN = Sh.OnAction & gcs

                    If BBN = NWP Then
                         If Gn = Sh.Title Then        ' nome grupo

                              ConfigB = Split(Sh.AlternativeText, ",")
                              If UBound(ConfigB) < 10 Then Exit Sub

                              If ConfigB(CfB(1)) <> "0" Then
                                   If ConfigB(CfB(6)) = "0" Then dsL = gcs + ConfigB(CfB(7)) Else dsL = Val(ConfigB(CfB(6))) + ConfigB(CfB(7))     'LINHA DE SAIDA
                                   If ConfigB(CfB(8)) = "0" Then dsC = gcs + ConfigB(CfB(9)) Else dsC = Val(ConfigB(CfB(8))) + ConfigB(CfB(9))     'COLUNA DE SAIDA


                                   If pre = Sh.OLEFormat.Object.Caption & ccs Then
                                        If ConfigB(CfB(2)) = "0" Then
                                             ConfigB(CfB(2)) = 1
                                             Cells(dsL, dsC).Value2 = ConfigB(CfB(4))
                                             Sh.BackgroundStyle = 3
                                             Sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground2
                                        Else
                                             If ConfigB(CfB(1)) = "1" Then
                                                  ConfigB(CfB(2)) = 0:
                                                  Cells(dsL, dsC).Value2 = ConfigB(CfB(3))
                                                  Sh.BackgroundStyle = 1:
                                                  Sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText2
                                             End If
                                        End If
                                   Else
                                        If ConfigB(CfB(1)) = "2" Then
                                             ConfigB(CfB(2)) = "0":
                                             Cells(dsL, dsC).Value2 = ConfigB(CfB(3))
                                             Sh.BackgroundStyle = 1:
                                             Sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText2
                                        End If
                                   End If
                              End If
                              Sh.AlternativeText = Join(ConfigB, ",")

                         End If
                    End If
               Next Sh
          End With
     End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Todos os shapes (incluindo Gráficos) no Excel possuem a propriedade AlternativeText.

Essa propriedade pode ser usada para armazenar informações. No seu caso, é possível sim usar essa propriedade pra guardar parâmetros sem que haja perda dos dados.

Segue um exemplo de uso:

```
Sub SetAlternativeText()
    Sheet1.Shapes("Rectangle 1").AlternativeText = "ABC"
End Sub 

Sub GetAlternativeText()
    MsgBox Sheet1.Shapes("Rectangle 1").AlternativeText
End Sub
```

De toda forma, talvez seja possível fazer esse armazenamento através de uma variável global.

Comment: já tinha feito uns testes , Até que funciona bem, mas para uso mais abrangente teria que montar todo um sistema .Não sei bem como se usaria uma global para isso, sendo que os dados são individuais marcando valores e estados dos objetos.

Comment: Você pode declarar as variáveis fora da função e usá-las quando for necessário em qualquer escopo do seu código.

E em caso de você precisar armazenar esses dados historicamente, é possível também declarar um array global e ir armazenando esses valores no array.

Comment: sim , até entendo, mas acho que esse artificio somente seria valido caso haja uma sobre carga ou problema envolvido com o uso das capacidades dos proprios objetos, uma vez localizado o objeto e lendo seu AlternativeText já se tem os parametros sem precisar de procurar em uma array e salvar em planilha , eu queria algo que funcionase como botão de opção e de seleção